# Geometry extraction from osm.pbf file using relation id with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, geojson, ogr2ogr, relation

### What works

If I need a GeoJSON file with the OpenStreetMap borders of Liechtenstein, I download `liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf` from GeoFabrik:

```
curl https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf -o liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf
```

Search for *Liechtenstein OpenStreetMap* and get its relation id (1155955):

[image]

Then, using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html), I create `liechtenstein_borders.geojson`:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON \
        -dialect sqlite \
        -sql "SELECT * FROM multipolygons WHERE osm_id=='1155955'" \
        liechtenstein_borders.geojson liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf \
        -nln main
```

The resulting GeoJSON nicely has a Liechtenstein shape:

[image]

---

### What does not work

The same method does not work for Norway. Relation id: [2978650](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2978650).

Download data:

```
curl https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/norway-latest.osm.pbf -o norway-latest.osm.pbf
```

Attempt extraction:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON \
        -dialect sqlite \
        -sql "SELECT * FROM other_relations WHERE osm_id=='2978650'" \
        norway_borders.geojson norway-latest.osm.pbf \
        -nln main
```

Result is an empty GeoJSON:

[image]

---

### Why?

What didn't I take into account when expecting the Norway-case to work just like the Liechtenstein one, and how can I fix the method? Ideally, I would like to be able to extract the geometry after having found [the relation id](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2978650).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is outside the cropped area from Geofabrik extract e.g right map at https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/norway.html
That's why you do not get it.

Two alternatives approaches using jq, curl, ogr2ogr and query-overpass (Node.js based CLI)

1. Using Overpass

```
echo "[out:json][timeout:300];(relation(2978650););(._;>>;);out body;>;out skel qt;" | query-overpass | jq -c '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "my_selection", "features": [.features[] | select( .geometry.type == "Polygon" or .geometry.type == "MultiPolygon")]}' | ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -f GeoJSON /tmp/output_norway_approach1.geojson /vsistdin/ -sql "SELECT 'Norway' AS name, ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM my_selection"
```

2. Using polygons export from relation

```
curl -s "https://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=2978650&params=0" | jq -c '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "my_selection", "features": [.geometries[] | {"type":"Feature","properties":{"name": "Norway"},"geometry": .}]}' >| output_norway_approach2.geojson
```

Second approach could be easily automated within Python if necessary

PS: There are some ways for improvements as in both cases, I do not bother about attributes of the relation and only care about geometry.